Curve of self-intersection $+1$ on complex algebraic surface
Given a compact complex (algebraic) surface, assume it contains a holomorphic curve whose self-intersection equals $+1$. Is there anything we can say about this complex surface? More precisely, will the existence of the $(+1)$-curve give any topological or geometric obstruction to the complex surface?
Any comments or discussions are appreciated.

Sticking to smooth surfaces: every birational class contains a surface with such a curve, so probably better stick to minimal surfaces. Projective plane clearly has such a curve; the Hirzebruch surface $F_n$ does iff $n$ is odd. No minimal surface with Kodaira dimension 0 does. Probably other people can say more.

Correction to the previous comment: the only Hirzebruch surface with an irreducible curve of self-intersection 1 is $F_1$.

This puts a restriction on the intersection form of the surface $Q: H_2(X, \mathbb{Z})\times H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})\to \mathbb{Z}$. The existence of a curve with self intersection $1$ means that $X$ has odd intersection form. Assuming that $X$ is simply connected, then if the intersection form is indefinite, i.e. there exists a surface with negative self intersection, the intersection form is isomorphic to the standard diagonal intersection $\mathrm{diag}(1,1,1,1,\cdots,1,-1,-1,\cdots, -1)$.
Heavy machinery from 4-manifold topology, specifically Donaldson's theorem and Freedman's classification of topological 4-manifolds, tell us that $X$ is homeomorphic to a connect sum of $\mathbb{C}P^2$'s and $\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$'s, the number of each given by $b_2^+$ and $b_2^-$, the dimension of maximal positive and negative definite subspaces of $(H_2(X,\mathbb{R}), Q)$ respectively. In the case where $b_2^+=1$ then there is only one $\mathbb{CP}^2$ and we can conclude that $X$ is homeomorphic to the blow up of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ $b_2^-$-times.
In the case where $Q$ is positive definite, there are too many intersection forms to classify directly.
